# Push data set alternate to Direct query

Tags: sql, powershell, powerbi, powerquery

I have created a powerBI using Direct query to get live reports. But when changing slicer filter in visual it takes long time to load data in visual table. So I searched for alternate to direct query and found Push dataset. But on analysis, seems push dataset uses API for streaming. Is it possible to use the push dataset for the below select query(Have 15 columns and 20k rows) as simple as direct query.

EX: select * from persons p
left join students s on s.id=p.id

Comment: No, streaming datasets doesn't work this way. They are not a replacement for your direct query dataset in this case.

Comment: Thank you Andrey,  But what is the use of Push dataset if not used for query?